# Swagger .NET endpoint request header without binding to parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

I'm looking for a way to add the a header to an endpoint (not all endpoints require it) so it can be retrieved in my middleware before the request hits the actual endpoint.

I'm currently using the [FromHeader] annotation, but that requires binding it to a parameter. This is not the wanted solution as I don't need the header in my controller method but only in my middleware.

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<Model>> GetModel([FromHeader(Name = "x-custom-header")] string customHeader)
```

This is the line I'm trying to convert to a more elegant solution. I'm not allowed to have parameters in my controller method declaration without using them.

Comment: Swagger tag? Do you want the header is explicit in the swagger contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This attribute indicate header on controller's actions :

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AddHeaderParameterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}
```

This operation filter check action with this attribute and modify the swagger contract :

```cs
public class AddHeaderParameterFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var addHeaders = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AddHeaderParameterAttribute), true).Cast<AddHeaderParameterAttribute>();
        foreach(var header in addHeaders)
        {
            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Schema = new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" },
                Name = header.Name,
                Required = header.Required
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You can specify the operation filter in `Startup.ConfigureServices` like :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { ... });
        c.OperationFilter<AddHeaderParameterFilter>();
    });
}
```

Then you can decorate action like :

```cs
[HttpGet]
[AddHeaderParameter( Name = "x-custom-header", Required = true)]
public IAction Get()
{ ... }
```